# How to make a glossary-like section with QR codes?

Tags: glossaries, appendices, thesis, qrcode

I'm writing a thesis and since I have to print it, I want to use QR (with the `qrcode` package) for all links in the document. The way I'd like to organize this is to have a section in the appendix, which contains all QR codes along with the written link.

I could do that manually, but is there a way to have this work like the glossary? Each QR code could then be defined with `\newqrcode{link}{label}` and referred to with `\qr{label}`. The text would then just contain some note pointing to the QR code. And in the appendix, there would be a list of all QR codes.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Edit:

Based on [@Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn)'s answer I created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcounter{qrlink}
\setcounter{qrlink}{0}

\newwrite\qrfile
\immediate\openout\qrfile=\jobname.qrs

\newfontfamily\qrfont{MinecraftTen.ttf}

\newcommand{\newqrcode}[2]{%
\stepcounter{qrlink}%
\immediate\write\qrfile{
  \noexpand\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}  
      \noexpand\draw (0,0) node{\noexpand\qrcode[height=3cm, nolink]{#1}};
      \noexpand\fill[white] (-4mm,-4mm) rectangle (4mm,4mm);
      \noexpand\node at (0,0){\noexpand\textbf{\noexpand\huge \noexpand\qrfont \theqrlink}};
      \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}
    \noexpand\end{minipage}
  \noexpand\begin{minipage}{10cm}
    \noexpand\section*{#2}
    \noexpand\url{#1} \noexpand\label{qr\theqrlink}\\[1mm]
    Used on page \thepage
  \noexpand\end{minipage}\\
}%
\hyperref[qr\theqrlink]{\theqrlink}
}

\newcommand{\printqrcodes}{
  \immediate\closeout\qrfile
  \section*{List of QR Codes}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of QR Codes}
  \input{\jobname.qrs}
}

\begin{document}

The link to the TeX Stack Exchange can be found in QR code \newqrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX Stack Exchange}.

This question in particular is in QR code \newqrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635426/how-to-make-a-glossary-like-section-with-qr-codes}{This Question}.

You can download the font I used for the numbering in QR code \newqrcode{https://www.fontspace.com/minecraft-ten-font-f40317}{Minecraft Font}. Make sure the file names match, and you're using XeTeX.

\appendix
\printqrcodes

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following code defines a wrapper command `\newqrcode` that prints a hyperlink in the document, but also prints a command to generate the qr code to an external `.qrs` file. In this file a counter is printed, the `\qrcode` command, and the label of the link. At the end of the document this file is closed and added to the document using `\input`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcounter{qrlink}
\setcounter{qrlink}{0}

\newwrite\qrfile
\immediate\openout\qrfile=\jobname.qrs

\newcommand{\newqrcode}[2]{%
\stepcounter{qrlink}%
\immediate\write\qrfile{\theqrlink. \noexpand\qrcode[height=1cm]{#1} #2\\}%
\href{#1}{#2} (\theqrlink)%
}

\begin{document}
A link: \newqrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SE}

Another link: \newqrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{also TeX.SE}

\immediate\closeout\qrfile
\section*{List of QR codes}
\input{\jobname.qrs}
\end{document}
```

Generated `.qrs` file:

```
1. \qrcode [height=1cm]{https://tex.stackexchange.com} TeX.SE\\
2. \qrcode [height=1cm]{https://tex.stackexchange.com} also TeX.SE\\
```

Result of compiling the main document:

[image]

Note that the url is passed as a normal argument to `\newqrcode` and from there to `\href`, this may cause problems with special characters in urls (that `\href` normally handles itself). So test carefully if you intend to actually use this solution instead of treating it as a proof of concept.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! I'm currently trying to make it more production-ready and will then add it to my question